# Tabs with FlatLists inside ScrollView - like Instagram or Twitter profile pages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I would like to have a set of tabs that each have a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView`. This is similar to the layout of Instagram or Twitter.

I am aware that there are some issues with having a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` and getting onEndReached to be triggered as only the `ScrollView`'s scroll events are registered?

This results in the inner `onEndReached` being called immediately on load and then over and over again...

If you make the ScrollView scrollEnabled false and `flex: 1` instead of `flexGrow: 1` then you can get the inner FlatLists to scroll but the outer content doesnt... This looks like this:

[image]

I think there are a lot of people who are struggling with this problem and I can't find a really clear solution anywhere.

I have also tried to implement `react-navigation-collapsible` with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` to create the tabs. However, you can't implement a pull-to-refresh on the whole screen?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I've also looked into implementing: [FlatList inside ScrollView doesn't scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098599/flatlist-inside-scrollview-doesnt-scroll)

AND I've looked at dynamically toggling the scrollEnabled property (even though it creates a re-render. This ALMOST works... but there is an issue with the ScrollView height being `flexGrow: 1` and the inner `FlatList` not filling the space...

**SECOND UPDATE**

This snack almost does the right thing... https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/collapsible-header-with-tabview
It uses `react-native-tab-view` and collapses the header using animation. If the header was a component, it could fetch data on load but you would only get a pull-to-refresh on the inner list (unlike Instagram).

**Related questions:**

There is an issue with onEndReached being called infinitely
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18887
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6002

FlatList cannot work right inside a ScrollView...
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12827#issuecomment-320509824

Flatlist inside ScrollView
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19971

FlatList inside ScrollView doesn't scroll
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19971

FlatList child is calling onEndReached on render
- https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/501

React Native Nested Listview Triggers onEndReached Multiple Times
- [React Native nested ListView triggers onEndReached multiple times on loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940820/react-native-nested-listview-triggers-onendreached-multiple-times-on-loading?rq=1)

When FlatList wrapped inside ScollView, onEndReached doesnt work expected.
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22008

Twitter-like profile layout - [How to create Twitter like profile layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556390/how-to-create-twitter-like-profile-layout) But I believe that the answer is now not correct.

Comment: Have tried `FlatList` of `react-native-gesture-handler`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Have tried FlatList of react-native-gesture-handler?

Comment: Sorry for mistake. react-native-gesture-handler has its own FlatList component. I suggest to try that.

Comment: It’s more the onEndReached working. Is this a problem you have solved before using a FlatList from this library inside a ScrollView?

Comment: @AlexChin Did you end up with a solution? I am facing the same issues as you did.

Comment: @AlexChin Is there any update regarding this? I am trying to build the same thing.

Comment: Did you solve it? trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should work with Animated api to handle the translateY of the content of TabView and the header.

For example:

```
<View>
   <Header />
   <TabView /> //With lists
<View>
```

Your Header should have a `position: 'absolute'` and a fixed height, and your TabView should have a paddingTop transparent to match the Header height.
Once you scroll one or other list, you should move the Header with `transform: [{ translateY }]` and your TabView too, so it can match the position of the Header until it clamps.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, didn't saw your update about the expo example.

Your expo example has some errors. For example if you scroll one list (to hide the header) your second list will have a blank space.

You should set the height of the list (TabView containing the lists) to be the  window height - header size clamped.
With this you can set translateY of the tabview to be the size of the header. Once you start scroll up, you should translateY both the header and the tabview until it clamps. From that point you should only scroll the list.

Another solution would be increase the height of tabView onScroll to match the translateY of header

Comment: translating the header is fine. But translating the tabview that contains the list is very bug, since the animated value comes from the list within the tabview.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to solve the issue:

```js
<ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[1]} //give any view index which you wana stick
          >
          <Header1 />
          <TabBar />
          <ViewPager
            ref={viewPagerRef}
            style={{
              flexGrow: 1,
            }}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            initialPage={0}
            orientation="horizontal">
            <Page1 key="1" />
            <Page2 key="2" />
            <Page3 key="3" />
          </ViewPager>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flat list instead of scroll view in header user your header code and in footer use your footer code even you can new flat list in header and foot and so on loop it will scroll full-page and don't have virtualization warning fix and in that why you can you multiple type of view in one flat list

```
<FlatList
                bounces={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={WhatsNewAPiUser}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                ListFooterComponent={UserListFooterForActivityLoader}
                ListHeaderComponent={UserListHeaderForTrending}
                renderItem={UserRenderItemForWhatsNEW}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
                onEndReached={async () => {
                  if (WhatsNewAPiUser.length > pageNumberwhatsnewapi) {
                    LoadMoreHomeWhatsNewUser();
                  }
                }}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={onRefresh}
                    onRefresh={() => HomeWhatsNewUser()}
                  />
                }
              />
```