# How Instagram implemented two scrolls in the profile Page

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile, instagram

I am facing an issue while developing a social app similar to instagram and twitter.

I can't seem to clone the profile page on Instagram and I don't understand how they have done it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5MrB.jpg)

If you can see that the scroll bar here doesnt start from the top, from which i can see that the flatlist or similar starts from the bottom part. BUT at the same time I can scroll from the top part and It will be responsive both to the top and bottom part. All that and the tabs selector will be sticky after scrolling.

Can someone explain how they have done that? Did you use both scrollView and Flatlist at the same time?
Or how?

It would be really helpful because i am stuck here.

Thank you

I tried so many React custom components as well as manually merging between Flatlist and ScrollView. Nothing has done it so far.

Comment: Quick searching (as in, 30-seconds) finds this: [Building Instagram profile screen with Compositional Layout](https://nemecek.be/blog/72/building-instagram-profile-screen-with-compositional-layout) ... might be worth a look.

Comment: @DonMag I am using react native

Comment: Searching for `"react native" instagram profile` or `"react native" instagram clone` pulls up a LOT of results...

Comment: I have done this and done a lot of research. None of these tutorials or blogs refer to the problem I am facing. They are not even implementing it. They are just doing a normal profile page that has an overall scroll.

Comment: OK - I don't use React Native, but I would assume there is either an equivalent to CollectionView with Compositional Layout, or a way to "wrap" native iOS controls. Or... *"Can someone explain how they have done that? Did you use both scrollView and Flatlist at the same time? Or how?"* -- maybe it wasn't done with React Native?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693590/tabs-with-flatlists-inside-scrollview-like-instagram-or-twitter-profile-pages?rq=1

This explains it as well. Still no answer for that